# UICollectionViewCell adding badge

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview

I want to add badge to my UICollectionViewCell when user press Long click on cell. Here is my code :

```
- (void)activateDeletionMode:(UILongPressGestureRecognizer *)gesture
{
    if (gesture.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan)
    {      
        NSIndexPath *indexPath = [_favoriteCollection indexPathForItemAtPoint:[gesture locationInView:_favoriteCollection]];
        UICollectionViewCell *cell = [_favoriteCollection cellForItemAtIndexPath:indexPath];
       //M13BadgeView *badgeView = [[M13BadgeView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(-12,-12, 24.0, 24.0)];
        M13BadgeView *badgeView = [[M13BadgeView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(200,200, 24.0, 24.0)];
        badgeView.text = @"1";
        [cell addSubview:badgeView];
        [cell bringSubviewToFront:badgeView];

    }
}
```

And this is how my cell Look after long click :
[image]

As you can seen the little red coin in my cell is the badge and it's always looking like that even when I change the frame it never change her position, example :

```
//M13BadgeView *badgeView = [[M13BadgeView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(-12,-12, 24.0, 24.0)];
M13BadgeView *badgeView = [[M13BadgeView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(200,200, 24.0, 24.0)];
```

Also I've tried to use `[cell bringSubviewToFront:badgeView];` or `[_favoriteCollection bringSubviewToFront:badgeView];` but it didn't worked.

**Note I'm using [this library](https://github.com/Marxon13/M13BadgeView) for badge

**Update** Thank's to luke answer  setting maskToBounds to false now my badge appear but I got another small issue the border of cell are shown in badge check this :
[image]

Comment: have you checked wether or not the cell´s property `maskToBounds` is set to `false`?

Comment: @luk2302 Setting maskToBounds or ClipToBounds solved part of my issue please check my update , and post your comment as answer.

Comment: is your border still a problem / bug?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To cause the badge to be displayed correctly you have to ensure the cell does not clip its contents to its bounds. Therefore you need to set the property `clipsToBounds` to `false`. That will cause the badge to be rendered outside its superviews frame.

After looking in the code of your used library I found out that after changing the `text` property of the badge a method called `autoSetBadgeFrame` is called. This function will cause the frame to be changed with no respect to the previously set frame. To change that behavior you should specify the alignment using the two properties `horizontalAlignment` and `verticalAlignment`. Setting the frame explicitly will cause some of its sublayers to maybe be displayed incorrectly. And you probably should add the subview to the cell **before** setting the text. This order will cause the already explained `autoSetBadgeFrame` to have a valid superview to align to.

Regarding the border: how do you specify the border?

Answer (score 1):

Use :

```
[[cell contentView] addSubview:badgeView];
```

Comment: Nope it didn't helped always same issue

Comment: Are you able to fetch your 'cell' this way. I think, your cell is null, try printing it.

Comment: Why don't you use :          UICollectionViewCell *cell = (UICollectionViewCell *)[[gesture view] superview];

Comment: Yeah I'm getting the correct cell this is NSLog example : `Cell x : 383.000000 ; cell Y : 0.000000`

Comment: What is this 'x' and 'y' ? I am asking for NSLog(@"My Long press cell : %@", cell) ;

Comment: It's getting the cell I got NSLog for cell position and cell Title and it work's fine

Comment: Try adding it to center, [badgeView setCenter:[cell center]]; . Also print 'badgeView'.